# Referencing a blade layout from a view inside a folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have organised my app to have switchable themes. I have several themes. Each theme has its own layout.

The image shows how i have organised my themes inside the views folder:

[image]

How can i reference my layout here `@extends('layouts.app')` ?

Does blade use dot notation for nesting or does a slash `/` do?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade uses dot notation to specify nesting. Unless you've configured a different views path though Blade will look relative to the `resources/views` directory. In which case you would need `@extends('themes.default.layouts.app')`.